# this.isModified is not working in findOneAndUpdate pre hook?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to check if nickname is changed or not when a user document is updated. `isModified` function properly works within `save pre hook` but does not work within `findOneAndUpdate`.

And I know that I can use `this._update` but I need both old value and new value in my case.

Can someone explain why I can't use `isModified` here and how can I get the solution?

**Controller:**

```
const updateProfile = asyncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ uid }, req.body, { new: true })
    // Other codes
})
```

**findOneAndUpdate hook:**

```
UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {    
    if(this.isModified('nickname')){
        // Some codes
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes), you can't use `isModified` function within `findOneAndUpdate pre hook`. You'll either have to execute an explicit query within the `findOneAndUpdate pre hook`, or convert it to a `save pre hook`.